# If the SELECT SQL Server value is null, the query takes 5 minutes C #

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a very silly problem. I am doing a select, and I want that when the value comes null, return an empty string. When there is value in sql query, the query occurs all ok, but if there is nothing in the query, I have to give a sqlCommand.CommandTimeout greater than 300, and yet sometimes gives timeout. Have a solution for this?

```
public string TesteMetodo(string codPess)
    {
        var vp = new Classe.validaPessoa();
        string _connection = vp.conString();
        string query = String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teste cliente WHERE cod_pess = {0}", codPess);
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connection))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {

                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if(dr.HasRows)
                        return "";
                    return codPess;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: [StackOverflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: You are returning an empty string when that query returns rows. As it is a `COUNT`, it always returns one row: the count. I guess you want to know the actual count returned and not if the query returned rows (which is always one row), right?

Comment: What is the type of cod_pes?

Comment: According to your tags you are using SQL-Server. An SQL query against a table that has a Space in the table name requires special attention. Try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [teste cliente] WHERE ...` instead. Besides that @Andrew is correct...you will always return an empty string.

Comment: And please read up on parameterizing queries. It's not done using `String.Format`.

Comment: Still there, Gabriel?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably validate in the UI and pass an integer.

You can combine the usings to a single block. A bit easier to read with fewer indents.

Always use parameters to make the query easier to write and avoid Sql Injection. I had to guess at the SqlDbType so, check your database for the actual type.

Don't open the connection until directly before the .Execute. Since you are only retrieving a single value you can use .ExecuteScalar. .ExecuteScalar returns an Object so must be converted to int.

```
    public string TesteMetodo(string codPess)
    {
        int codPessNum = 0;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(codPess, out codPessNum))
            return "codPess is not a number";
        var vp = new Classe.validaPessoa();
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(vp.conString))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teste cliente WHERE cod_pess = @cod_pess", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@cod_pess", SqlDbType.Int).Value = codPessNum;
                conn.Open();
                int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (count > 0)
                    return "";
                return codPess;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```